# LESS compiler for Wordpress

Tags: php

can I compile some .less-files automatically by using Wordpress. I found just [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/)

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative see the lessphp Project: https://github.com/leafo/lessphp

Works fine and hase an team of contributor. But has not an out of the box function for WordPress; but uts only PHP and the WP has the right Hooks. Do you will only use in themes, then its also fine, that you include this and it works with your requirements and no dependencies to an plugin.

For an easy use in WP, see this project https://github.com/sanchothefat/wp-less
its an wrapper and use lessphp; but an new dependencies. But its better as an plugin, if the customer change the plugin with updates and other doings, and easy to use.

Comment: Great, I included it in my Starter-Theme - Vielen Dank Frank  So can easily  import styles from your main `style.less` into the `editor-style.less` without writing it two times just code `@import "wordpress-styles-for-editor.less";` in it - GREAT

Comment: welcome. Do you use now the lessphp alone, or also the wp-less class?

Comment: Both solutions (yours and kaiser's) are nice, but one question - how can I include my css/styles.less file into theme editor, so that I don't have to ssh to my server each time I need to change some styles?

Comment: Do you will change stylesheet via backend, then it is important that you update your style via lessphp. But on the default editor of WP is it not possibel to edit files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look at #BW LESS CSS Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bw-less-css/installation/) in the repo.

From the plugins description:

> Attach `.less` files to your template using the plugin admin page, under #BW Options -> LESS-CSS
>
> - Specify files relative to your theme root (eg. style.less for a file in the root)
> - If using a specialty stylesheets (eg. for print), select the media type
> - To target mobile devices, check the mobile checkbox (see FAQ below) 3d. To minify (compress) the compiled CSS, check the minify checkbox
>     Manually include .less files:
> - To hard-code a `.less` file into a template, use `<?php bw_less_css( $file, $args = array() ) ?>` in a template file, called by `after_setup_theme` action.

```
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'lesscss_include' );
    function lesscss_include() {
        bw_less_css( 'style.css' );
        bw_less_css( 'css/print.css', array( 'media' => 'print', 'minify' => true, 'mobile' => false, 'force' => false );
    }
```

> Files are relative to the theme root, and the less compiler will save the `.css` to the same path as the `.less` file.
>   If you are using `@import` to compile multiple stylesheets into a single file, such as Twitter's Bootstrap, turn on developer mode while developing to force the stylesheets to recompile every time the page is loaded. If developer mode is off, imported stylesheets will not be recompiled unless you re-save the main stylesheet. If manually including less files using `bw_less_css()`, set `'force' => true` argument.

Comment: Upvoting appreciated (if you like the a)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are plugins around that make use of that library.

For example see [wp-less](https://github.com/sanchothefat/wp-less) that compiles enqueued LESS stylesheets into CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid compile CSS each time visit your website, unless you have a cache solution. I suggest you use the the task runner of [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) for accomplish compile LESS once only. You can compile LESS files upon your development environment while editing files, you can add watchers as well for fast compile even add a *livereload* for fast development.